# simulation or performance evaluation with Ethereum testnet

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, blockchain-interoperation, openblockchain

I was if you could help me about simulation.

How can I simulate the performance of my following IoT-based Application with Ethereum testnet?

In my senario,there are some nodes that store sensor data in Distributed Hash Tables (DHTs) while the pointer to the DHT storage address is stored in the blockchain.

How I can show the performance of system and other parameters such as required time to add new block, proccessing time, update peer's blockchain with received transaction?